# Drawing a diagonal line?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and need help drawing a diagonal line.

I want it to go from the bottom left of a box to the top centre. The dimensions of the box are user entered so I would prefer it to be something like `width/2` etc. so it always works.

How would I go about creating this line?

Comment: Are you kidding? Use google. There are many resources available for doing something as simple as drawing a line.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you need to do:

1. What is the bottom left corner location (x,y)
2. Given the width and height of the box, where is the center
3. Draw line from bottom left (x,y) to the center

Then, after writing that down, convert that to Java

Answer (score 0):

If you draw something in Java (when overriding the paint() method of a view) you have to keep in mind that de y-axis of the element goes down instead of up.

you have something like this:

```
-----1-----2------> X
|
|
1
|
|
2
|
|
3


Y
```